# Network Flow Optimization

Tags: optimization, network-flow

1. Suppose we have a network with node set $N = \{1,\dots, n\}$ and arc set $E$. $(i, j) \in E$ if there is a link between node $i$ and node $j$. We need to send $L$ commodities
   from their respective origin to destination node. The multicommodity flow
   problem has the following specifications:

(a) There are $L$ origin-destination (O-D) pairs of nodes $(s_1, t_1), \dots,(s_L, t_L)$,
and $d^k$ is the amount of flow that must be sent from $s_k$ to $t_k$ for $k =
1, \dots, L$.

(b) $u_{i,j}$ is the capacity (shared by all commodities) on the arc $(i, j)$ for any
$(i, j) \in E$.

(c) $c^k_{i,j}$ is the cost of sending one unit of commodity $k$ through arc $(i, j)$.
Write down an optimization model for the above problem to minimize the
total cost.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [*multicommodity flow problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem).  A formulation is given [here](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=ormpug&docsetTarget=ormpug_decomp_examples01.htm&docsetVersion=15.1&locale=en).